# GORM GPARS Integration Test

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, gpars

I am trying to integration-test the Gorm pessimistic lock, and simulating with multithreading the access from many servers simultaneously, but in each thread I don't get the results expected. This is my code:

```
@Test
void testLockInBetweenCheck() {
def tid = IdocTidInfo.findByTid("AC10870D0E12504F3E88D575") //here tid is not null
withPool{
      [1,2].eachParallel{ tids ->
     IdocTidInfo.withTransaction{ tid ->
        def t = IdocTidInfo.findByTid("AC10870D0E12504F3E88D575") // here is t is null
```

I can't figure out what's happening, I supposed my Hibernate sessionFactory is not bound to each thread, and that Domain.withTransaction I should work, but it didn't.

Any help?

Comment: post the answer to the question and mark it as the accepted solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was related to the Set Up method of the integration test, where I bootstraped the data in memory. Once I move that to Bootstrap, the closures from threads could bind the hibernate sessions! Thanks anyways!!

Comment: Can you post the entire example class? I need an example to compare to. My threads couldn't bind to the session either.

Comment: I had a similar problem. Could you please post your code.